# Doesn't Vary: * simply make HTTP responses uncachable?

Tags: http, caching, http-caching

If so, I'm surprised that such a thing even exists. Why would you need such a thing? Seems to me, you could use other headers to (more easily) prevent caching.

Answer (score 2):

That's one effect it has, but it also tells the client that the response was selected based upon things that couldn't be expressed in a Vary header.